# Rspec for testing Oauth of Yelp API

Tags: ruby, testing, oauth, rspec, tdd

I'm trying to write a Yelp API wrapper.  I'm thinking on creating a Client class that will deal with the OAuth object instantiation. Something like this:

```
class Client
    @site = "api.yelp.com"

    def initialize(options = {})
      @consumer_key = options[:consumer_key]
      @consumer_secret = options[:consumer_secret]
    end

    private

    def consumer
      @consumer ||= OAuth::Consumer.new(@consumer_key, @consumer_secret, {:site => "http://#{@site}"}) 
    end
end
```

I would like to know what would be a good way to test this desired behavior using Rspec. I am completely lost in how to start writting my tests. How would I test OAuth in this scenario?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, that would be useful to test authentication with Omniauth. I am using OAuth, and I am not even expecting to have any callback to mock...